# Android SQLite prepared statement lifecycle

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The SQLite prepared statements seems like a good way to execute queries versus raw sql statements. I'm just wondering how long they should be kept around.

Is it safe to statically compile the statement, i.e. only compile it once and keep using the same statement for many queries? 
If this is not thread safe then what about on a thread local?
Conversely are prepared statements still preferred if you only use them once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The advantages of Prepared Statements are:**

- As the execution plan get cached, performance will be better.
- It is a good way to code against SQL Injection as escapes the input
  values.
- When it comes to a Statement with no unbound variables, the database
  is free to optimize to its full extent. The individual query will be
  faster, but the down side is that you need to do the database
  compilation all the time, and this is worse than the benefit of the
  faster query.

For Java Programming have a look on [Statement and PreparedStatement](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1993620575194)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you know if SQLite also caches the prepared statements after compiling ? that is if i compile two statements with the same SQL will it be able to reuse the first compiled statement. If there is a cache do you know when it is cleared, maybe when the database connection is terminated?.